# how to break from a loop when using sse intrinsics?

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

```
__m128* pSrc1 = (__m128*) string;
__m128 m0 = _mm_set_ps1(0);    //null character

while(1)
{
    __m128 result = __m128 _mm_cmpeq_ss(*pSrc1, m0);

    //if character is \0 then break

    //do some stuff here

    pSrc1++;
}
```

I have a string whose length can be a multiple of 16.
How do I break out of the loop if _mm_cmpeq_ss returns equal?

Comment: Any reason why you can't do something like while(__m128 result != '\0')

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but aren't the 128-bit XMM registers for floating point ops?

Comment: @CHill60 Because you can't compare a 128 bit vector with a char for equality

Comment: @legends2k No. There are many integer operations on XMM registers, like bitwise and/or/add/sub/mul/mask for integer types of length 8,16,32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz ... oops, of course *hanging head in shame*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to break out of the loop when you first encounter a `\0` then you'll need to do something like this:

```
__m128i* pSrc1 = (__m128i *)string;         // init pointer to start of string
__m128i m0 = _mm_set1_epi8(0);              // vector of 16 `\0` characters

while (1)
{
    __m128i v0 = _mm_loadu_si128(pSrc1);    // get 16 chars from string
    __m128i v1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v0, m0);    // compare all 16 chars with '\0'
    int vmask = _mm_movemask_epi8(v1);      // get 16 comparison result bits
    if (vmask != 0)                         // if any bit is 1
        break;                              // we found a `\0`, break out of loop
    pSrc1++;                                // next 16 characters...
}
```

If you only want to test for `\0` characters in certain positions and ignore any others then you can change the `if (vmask != 0)` test to something which matches your specific requirements.

Comment: only m 17th, 33rd ...characters can be \0

Comment: i.e my strings length is always multiple of 16

Comment: OK - well this solution will still work (unless you want to ignore `\0` characters elsewhere ?). I've updated the answer to cover this possibility anyway.

Comment: Is `movemask` favoured over `ptest xmm,same`, to test for all-zero?  (If you're already using other SSE4.1 instructions, of course.)  The `test / jcc` can macro-fuse, so it's the same number of uops (movemask + test&branch  vs.  ptest + branch), but fewer instructions.  `movemask` has 3 cycle latency on Haswell (2 on SnB/IvB), while `ptest` is only 2 cycle latency even on Haswell.  `movmsk` can run on p0 only, while `ptest` can run on p0/p5 (Haswell), so it leaves both FMA ports free.  I think in most cases, `PTEST` would be a better choice.

Comment: Oops, nvm, `PTEST` is 2 uops on Haswell.  So it's probably slower than `movmsk` + `test`, if uop throughput is the bottleneck.   I guess it's only useful in cases where testing just the high bits isn't sufficient, or you can use it with 2 different operands (to get a free bitwise AND).  According to Agner Fog's table, `PTEST` is 1 fused-domain uop on SnB, but still 2 unfused uops for the execution ports.  On IvB/HSW, 2 uops even in the fused domain.

Comment: @PeterCordes: well it's a fairly old question, and I probably didn't want to make any assumptions about SSE4.1 being available, but yes, it's probably worth benchmarking with both to see if it makes any significant difference.