# Find the first instance of a character using simd

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I am trying to find the first instance of a character, in this case '"' using simd (AVX2 or earlier). I'd like to use _mm256_cmpeq_epi8, but then I need a quick way of finding if any of the resulting bytes in the __m256i have been set to 0xFF. The plan was then to use _mm256_movemask_epi8 to convert the result from bytes to bits, and the to use ffs to get a matching index. Is it better to move out a portion at a time using _mm_movemask_epi8? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I should add, simd isn't necessary, in general I am just looking for the fastest approach. Perhaps some bit magic?

Comment: Your basic idea is sound - I have a feeling that there may already be a SIMD implementation much as you describe in a previous question on StackOverflow, but a quick search didn't turn it up. Note that what you're implementing is effectively `strchr` (or `memchr` if you know the length), and there may well already be SIMD-optimised implementations of this available. Note also that for strings that are not already in cache your function may well be memory bandwidth limited.

Comment: [Here's an SSE implementation which scans a string for a `'\0'`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524319/253056) (effectively `strlen`), which you might be able to adapt.

Comment: Relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245773/why-is-strchr-twice-as-fast-as-my-simd-code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the right idea with `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` -> `_mm256_movemask_epi8`.  That's the optimal way to implement this with AVX2.  `VPMOVMSKB r32, ymm` is the same speed as the XMM 16-byte version, so it would be a huge loss to unpack the two lanes of a 256b vector and movemask them separately and then recombine the integer results.  (Source: [Agner Fog's instruction table](http://agner.org/optimize/), or more recently https://uops.info/ has better data.  See other perf links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

Make the code inside the loop as efficient as possible by leaving the `ffs` or `_tzcnt_u32` until after you've identified a non-zero result from `_mm256_movemask_epi8`.

TEST/JCC can macro fuse into a single uop, but BSF/JCC doesn't, so it takes an extra instruction.  (And you'd be hard-pressed to get a C compiler to emit BSF/JCC anyway.  More likely branching on the result of `ffs` would give you some kind of test for the input being non-zero, then BSF, then add 1, then compare-and-branch.  That's obviously horrible compared to just testing the movemask result.)

(Update, **in C++20, use `std::countr_zero`.**  It can compile to a single `tzcnt`, instead of the off-by-one of `ffs`.  Since you've already checked for the mask being non-zero, hopefully can optimize to a single (`rep`) `bsf` instruction if it isn't sure all CPUs running the code will support `tzcnt`. If you can assume BMI1 in your target CPUs, which you usually can for AVX2 code, then enable that so you'll reliably get an efficient `tzcnt`.)

For related problems like `memcmp`, you can check `movemask == 0xFFFFFFFF` to check that all bytes matched; that's just as efficient as branching on it being non-zero to find if any elements matched.  (Then `std::countr_zero(~mask)` to find the first mismatch.  Or I guess `std::countr_one` in case any ISA has an instruction for that... but we know we're compiling for x86 so it'll internally have to use NOT / TZCNT anyway.)

---

As Paul R suggested, looking at some strlen, strchr, and memchr implementations may be informative.  There are multiple hand-written asm implementations in open-source libc implementations, and other places.  (e.g. glibc, and [Agner Fog's asmlib](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).)

Many of glibc's versions scan up to an alignment boundary, then use an unrolled loop that reads 64B at a time (in 4 SSE vectors, since I don't think glibc has an AVX2 version).  For `str` (not `mem`) functions, that's necessary for correctness: *[Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64)* (technically no in C++, but it's hard for the compiler to notice.  Safe in asm.)

To optimize for long strings, reduce overhead from testing the compare results by ORing the compare results together, and check that.  If you find a hit, go back and re-test your vectors to see which vector had the hit.

It may be somewhat more efficient to do the `ffs` on one 64-bit integer that you built up out of multiple movemask results (with shift and `|`).  Don't do that inside the loop, though, just test `mask1 | mask2` for non-zero (`or`/`jz keep_looping`).  It's useful for sorting out which of two vectors has the match if you were already unrolling, though.  Have a look at what Agner Fog's string functions do, or if you don't mind reading GPLed code, have a look at glibc.

---

Everything I've suggested here is stuff can be seen in asm in various glibc strategies for strlen, memchr, and related functions.  Here's [sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S;hb=HEAD) (LGPL license), but there may be another source file somewhere using more than baseline SSE2.  Or not, I might be thinking of a different function, there's probably nothing to be gained from SSE4, only maybe AVX (3-operand insns) and definitely AVX2 (256b integer vectors).

See also:

- glibc's [`strchr-avx2.S`](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strchr-avx2.S.html)  (codebrowser.dev has a nice source browser with a useful search for filenames / symbols).
- glibc's [`memchr-avx2.S`](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memchr-avx2.S.html)

---

[glibc's memchr](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/rawmemchr.S;h=ec2cb9c76c00d69fa5f4b069570cb0b1faab77e6;hb=892bb11e4eb1e2fa931e2e4f5268dafb848c87db) uses PMAXUB instead of POR.  I'm not sure if that's useful for some arcane microarchitectural reason, but it runs on fewer ports on most CPUs.  Perhaps that's desired, to avoid resource conflicts with something else?  IDK, seems weird, since it competes with PCMPEQB.

Perhaps the author was thinking of min/max operations because `pminub` *is* useful in glibc's `strlen` algorithm, where `pminub` *before* compare gives a zero byte iff either input has a zero.

Comment: The thought behind _mm_movemask_epi8 was that it looks like it is faster on newer processors than _mm256_movemask_epi8, even if it needs to be called twice. If it doesn't, then you get a savings on avoiding the extra call. This of course seems to be processor dependent, so on Haswell where they have equal latencies, the larger call (i.e. _mm256_movemask_epi8) seems to be a better approach.

Comment: @Jimbo: oh hmm, I hadn't notice that `PMOVMSKB r, v` in Agner Fog's table for Skylake is listed as 2-3c latency.  On Haswell, `VMOVMSKPS/D
r32, ymm` is 2c latency, but the xmm version is 3c latency!  That's surprising.  Where are you seeing that the 256b version is slower?  Are you sure the ymm version isn't faster on Skylake?

Comment: @Jimbo:  Anyway, the difference is at most one cycle of latency and no extra uops or throughput.  **`_mm256_movemask_epi8` is still the best you can do**.  Nothing you could do with the two halves separately can possibly be as good as just using one VPMOVMSKB r32, ymm.  Using a 128b movmsk on the upper lane would require extracting it first to the low 128b of a register, with a 3-cycle latency lane-crossing shuffle like VEXTRACTF128.

Comment: Anyway, keep in mind that testing the mask for a loop condition is only sensitive to latency for detecting mispredicts, and for feeding the mask to BSF or TZCNT (`ffs`) after the last iteration.  Speculative execution with branch prediction means that every conditional-branch instruction is a separate dependency chain.  I.e. control dependencies are not data dependencies.  Shorter latency on the flag input to a JCC doesn't affect throughput, only the latency before a branch mispredict can be detected.